Glass Dispersion Shader with blurred sides
I'm wondering how I could create that kind of shader (screenshot) in which only the sides are "blurred" or "rough", but the front and back are kind of clear.

My node setup for disperssed glass looks like this:

Thank you for any tips! :)

Hello, I think the effect you want is called tilt-shift or camera depth of field and if you want it custom (by default if its physically based it depends on the distance to your camera and the properties of your camera) you might want to do the effect in post-processing inside the compositor workspace with a gresycale mask and a blur node.

I don't think this is a shader thing... because the shader will not make the boundaries of your object blurred as they are in the reference image. I would agree with @Gorgious that this is most likely a tilt-shift effect.

@Gorgious Thank you for your answer. Maybe I didn't say it correctly. I'm talking about the roughness on the sides. Because I feel like the front of the object has less roughness but the sides have more roughness. Am I right?

Do you mean Roughness as in the input from your different BSDFs ?

@Gorgious Yes, indeed. Don't you feel like that the sides of the object are rougher than the front glass which seems to be clearer? Or is it just an illusion.

I think it's not the roughness but refraction artifacts, the light rays from the lower face come in the camera at a direct angle while the light rays from the sides bounce a few times before going into the camera which tends to scatter the light
